# Response.redirect not letting JavaScript finish VB.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to send an email whenever a certain button is clicked, after that email is sent i want to redirect the user to another page. But the problem is that the program is redirecting the user before the JavaScript code finished and sends the mail. 
Is there anyway I could still use `response.redirect` instead of `window.location.href` while using JavaScript?

My code is:

```
Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     btnConfirm.Click

  'Send Tutor Email
 divScript.InnerHtml += "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/mail.js'>  </script>" & Environment.NewLine
 divScript.InnerHtml += "<script>" & Environment.NewLine
 divScript.InnerHtml += "SendTutorNewOrder(accountName, email, strTiming) " & Environment.NewLine
 divScript.InnerHtml += "</script>" & Environment.NewLine

 Response.redirect("exampleWebsite.com")
```

Comment: no, but you can "redirect" in javascript - but you still need to wait for the `SendTutorNewOrder` function to finish (at a guess, it's asynchronous in nature)

Comment: @JaromandaX. Yes i tried doing that. However, window.location.href takes about two seconds to redirect the user. Is there any way to make window.location.href run faster?

Comment: When you say "redirecting the user before the JavaScript code finished" this not torally right. The javascript isn't even started. When redirecting, the body is completely ignored. Your "exampleWebsite.com" could be the one sending the html.

Answer (score 0):

End of "SendTutorNewOrder(accountName, email, strTiming)" mothod that you defined in client side, write code below

```
window.location.href = "exampleWebsite.com";
```

and delete

```
Response.redirect("exampleWebsite.com")
```

from server side